# Are quotation marks necessary?

Tags: grammaticality

For 8th grade recognition all students selected a quote they like. Is is necessary to put in quotation marks? The authors are acknowledged and the section is titled QUOTES.

Comment: If they're all quotations, and the acknowledgments are visually separated from the quotations, there's no need for the quote marks. They're there to separate the quotation from the rest of the text, and if that's already been done, they're just extra jots and tittles to clutter the page.

Comment: +1 not least for silently correcting OP's "quotes" to "quotations." But since we are dealing with eighth-graders, let's leave it at "jots" and omit the tittles.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I don't really understand why some peevers consider using the noun "quote" as a shorter way of saying of "quotation" as somehow any more incorrect than using the noun "demo" as a shorter way of saying "demonstration".

Answer (score 2):

It's really a matter of personal preference.

I prefer to write quotes with single quotation marks and then a tilde (~), but others will use a dash (-) with double quotes or even none at all.

> 'Quote' ~Author
>
> "Quote" ~Author
>
> 'Quote' -Author
>
> "Quote" -Author
>
> Quote ~Author
>
> Quote -Author

Some may even use italics:

> *Quote* ~Author
>
> *Quote* -Author

Just choose which style you like best.

Comment: What about italics? It's extremely common to use italics in lieu of quotes.

Comment: I shall edit my answer accordingly @Catija.

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks are used to distinguish the quote from other text. In a long list of quotes, you certainly could forego the marks.

For instance, here on Stack Exchange websites, I prefer not using quotation marks and using the default quotation block style:

> The trick is to enjoy life. Don't wish away your days, waiting for
>   better ones ahead.
>        ~ Marjorie Pay Hinckley

I would suggest that you make your decision based on design, meaning the design of your document.

Other ways you might do it:

The trick is to enjoy life. Don't wish away your days, waiting for better ones ahead.
(Marjorie Pay Hinckley)

The future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams.
(Eleanor Roosevelt)

“The trick is to enjoy life. Don't wish away your days, waiting for better ones ahead.” ~ Marjorie Pay Hinckley

“The future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams.” ~ Eleanor Roosevelt